# How to click the button under the layer or image?

Tags: html, css

imagine you have a clock 700px/700px and each quoter is a button highlighted on hover

```
<header> 
 <div class="opening">
  <div class="clock">
    
   <img class="clock" src="./materialy-graficzne/stoper-01.png" usemap="#image-map">
   <img class="clockArrow" src="materialy-graficzne/stoper-01-arrow.png">
   <map name="image-map">
    <area class="areaA" alt="link to ecurcum section" title="ecurcum" href="#eC" coords="699,2,352,349" shape="rect">
    <area class="areaB" alt="link to ewasab section" title="ewasab" href="#eW" coords="352,351,699,699" shape="rect">
    <area class="areaC" alt="link to eginger section" title="eginge" href="#eG" coords="349,352,3,699" shape="rect">
    <area class="areaD" alt="link to esafforn section" title="esaffro" href="#eS" coords="348,349,1,1" shape="rect">
   </map>

  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

The problem is that div.clock includes also the clock arrow 700px/700px and it's over the clock and rotates.

Because of the problem with layers i can't click on the buttons. Do you have any ideas how to deal with it? thx

[screan of a clock example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV9gq.png)

Comment: I think adding a screenshot will help us understand the issue better. If the image is on top of it button you want to click, you have no choice but to make the arrow move-on so that you can click it. But if the entire button is not clickable, you will need to include a top div that you can click on.

Comment: Have you tried pointer-events: none on the upper layer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be useful, but what you could try doing is using the CSS property "z-index" to make the buttons be above your clock.

Again, I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I hope I helped..